# Is the family $\mathcal{U} = \left\lbrace U\left(\left[0, n\right]\right): n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$ relatively compact?

Tags: probability-theory, compactness

Is the family  $\mathcal{U} = \left\lbrace U\left(\left[0, n\right]\right): n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$ relatively compact?

I got hint, that I should use Prokhorov's theorem (probability calculus), but I don't know how to proceed from this.

All help will be appreciated.

Edit:

"In measure theory Prokhorov's theorem relates tightness of measures to relative compactness (and hence weak convergence) in the space of probability measures." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem))

The relevant part connecting tightness with relatively compact (from [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures)):

"Furthermore, by Prokhorov's theorem, a collection of probability measures on $X$ is tight if and only if it is precompact [relatively compact] in the topology of weak convergence."

Comment: What does "conditionally compact" mean?

Comment: It should be "relatively compact", I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question but:

If $\mu_n$ has uniform distribution on $[0,n]$ then the sequence $(\mu_n)$ is not tight and hence not relatively compact.

If it would be tight then there exists $K$ such that $\mu_n([K,\infty)) <\frac1  2 $ for all $n$. But this implies $\frac {n-K} n <\frac 1  2$ for all $n >k$  and we get a contradiction by letting $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Could you explain me the part with implication $\frac{n-K}{n} < \frac{1}{2}$? I am a bit confused there, where did this fraction come from.

Comment: @ljaniec $\mu_n [K,\infty)$ is th measure  of $[K,\infty)\cap [0,n])$ divided by $n$. Since   $[K,\infty)\cap [0,n])=[K,n]$ we get $\mu_n [K,\infty)=\frac {n-K} n$.